# Symfony2's FormTypeGuesser Annotation based behavior fails in prod

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, annotations

I'm developing an app that use generator Commands called from a service to generate Entities upon user config input in a web Form.

I use regular Doctrine Types, [boolean, integer, string, text, ...] in a dropDown to allow for field type configuration. Plus a custom Type "ValueList" that is used to provide the end user with options from which to choose in a DropDown box in the generated Form, for the Generated Entity.

In dev it works smoothly. But in prod, any newly generated Entity, that use "ValueList" Fields, get this fields rendered as input text, not Select as expected.

If I manually `rm app/cache/prod/annotations/*` it works upon refresh.

I implemented this by creating an Annotation @ValueList that gets added to the just generated entity's propper Field. And a `class FormTypeGuesser extends DoctrineOrmTypeGuesser` that for any field that DoctrineOrmTypeGuesser guesses as a 'text' field I check for the @ValueList annotation.

So, is there a way to tell the Annotations Parser to find any new change?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the `annotations.file_cache_reader` definition and provide your own cache service extending the base class `FileCacheReader`.

Then you will just have to implement in your service a method that force generation of cache for a specific entity class.

You can find the definition of `annotations.file_cache_reader` here  `symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/annotations.xml`

More information on service overriding [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration).

Comment: Thanks! I decided to delete cache files upon entity modification. Otherwise FileCacheReader would check every time. But's a valuable info any way

Answer (score 0):

While reading my own code to past snippets I realized that I'm using the Symfony annotation_reader service, which is actually the `FileCacheReader` class, that, unless initialized with debug parameter to true, won't track for changes in the Class.

As I cant (I think)[edit: I can as per @rolebi 's] override how Symfony instantiates this service, and I don't want to create a basic AnnotationReader and register Annotations to it. I decided to 'manually' delete the related cache files.

```
public function clearAnnotationsCache(DocumentType $docDefinition)
{
    // /home/juanmf/Work/GDocs/docdigital1/app/cache/[prod|dev]
    $envCacheDir = $this->_kernel->getCacheDir();
    $files = glob(sprintf( '%s/annotations/%s*', $envCacheDir, sha1($docDefinition->getClassFqcn())));
    foreach ($files as $file) { 
        if (is_file($file)) {
            unlink($file); 
        }
    }
}
```

`sha1($docDefinition->getClassFqcn()))` matches the way the FileCacheReader name the cached classes. FQCN like `'DocDigital\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User'`

This way I just delete the minimum amount of cached elements.